# Why does my Web API / REST / Windsor code get routed in this direction?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I probably will not be able to provide enough information/insight for anybody to answer this question absolutely, but I'm hoping, by giving the best overview I can of the dilemma, to get thrown a bone that will be crunchy and marrowful enough to be of help.

I'm trying to trace the path a REST call takes through my code so that I can see how I can get it, at a certain point, to go here instead of there (where it is going).

Specifically, I don't know why the GetCount() method here:

```
namespace NRBQ.Client
{
    public class RESTNRBQDelivery : INRBQDelivery
    {
        INRBQClientSettings NRBQClientSettings;
        IRESTAPIClient RESTAPIClient;

        public RESTNRBQDelivery(IRESTAPIClient RESTAPIClient, INRBQClientSettings NRBQClientSettings)
        {
            this.NRBQClientSettings = NRBQClientSettings; 
            this.RESTAPIClient = RESTAPIClient;
        }

        public RESTNRBQDelivery(IRESTAPIClient RESTAPIClient, INRBQClientSettings NRBQClientSettings, AuthenticationHeaderValue AuthHeader)
        {
            this.NRBQClientSettings = NRBQClientSettings;
            this.RESTAPIClient = RESTAPIClient;
            this.RESTAPIClient.AuthHeader = AuthHeader;
        }

        public int GetCount()
        {
            var res = RESTAPIClient.GET<int>(0
               , new Uri(NRBQClientSettings.NRBQAPI)
               , "api/deliveries/Count"
               );

            if (res.status != RequestResultStatus.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception(res.message);
            }

            return res.result;
        }
```

...calls this:

```
namespace SeaStore.Data.Legacy.NRBQ
{
    public class NRBQSQLRepository : INRBQRepositoryInterface
    {
        private INRBQRepositorySettings Settings;
        private IMSAccessHelper MSAccessHelper;

        public NRBQSQLRepository(INRBQRepositorySettings settings, IMSAccessHelper MSAccessHelper)
        {
            this.Settings = settings;
            this.MSAccessHelper = MSAccessHelper;
        }

        public int GetNRBQEntity()
        {
    . . . // this is the method that is called
```

I would prefer that it would call this class, which lives beneath the same folder as the code above:

```
namespace SeaStore.Data.Legacy.NRBQ
{
    public class NRBQDeliveryRepository : INRBQDeliveryRepository
    {
        private INRBQRepositorySettings Settings;
        private IMSAccessHelper MSAccessHelper;

        public NRBQDeliveryRepository(INRBQRepositorySettings settings, IMSAccessHelper MSAccessHelper)
        {
            this.Settings = settings;
            this.MSAccessHelper = MSAccessHelper;
        }

        public int GetCount()
        {
            return 42; // <= I want it to go to here, not to its sibling
        }
```

Again, this is just the tip of the meltburg, and I know it's unreasonable to expect an answer from this tidbit of info, but: Is there some tool or procedure by which I can suss out just why the path through the code takes this fork rather than the other?

Comment: Try looking for something like this:    
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
or this:
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(

Comment: Thanks; it would seem another thing to search for to get the same results would be just opening every WebAPIConfig.cs file.